# How to set a background image centred in my website?

Tags: html, css

I have a query based on the following CSS and HTML code (see below).

I have a background image that spans the whole browser page (left to right), which is not what I'm after.

How can I get the background image to stay within the boundaries of my main content canvas, i.e. centered 850x600px and anything outside just be white?

```
    body {
background-color: #ffffff;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
background-image: url(images/background.jpg);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
background-attachment: scroll;
}

#main {

width:850px;
margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
border: 0px solid #f0f0f0;

}

<body>

<div id="main">
<img src="images/female_model.jpg" id="female_model" alt="" />
<div id="colwrap1">
<img src="images/nav_bar.jpg" id="nav_bar" alt="" />
<img src="images/site_name.jpg" id="site_name" alt="" />
</div>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to attach the background to the `main` DIV, then specify the background there. It sounds like you want the background to be centered horizontally (`background-position: 50%;`) but repeat for the vertical extent of the `main` DIV (`background-repeat: repeat-y;`).

```
body {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#main {
  background-image: url(images/background.jpg);
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-position: 50%;

  // rest as before ...
  width: 850px;
  ...
}

<div id="main">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ...
```

If your background image does not appear it could be because the image is inaccessible or the `main` DIV has no height--that could happen if `female_model` and `colwrap1` both float.

Comment: Thanks for that but unfortunately my background image is no longer appearing. FYI, my background image file is a vertical strip that has a dimension of 22x600. Any further help would be appreciated.I am using Chrome or FF on Mac OS X. Thanks.

Comment: Then leave out Domonic's background-repeat line

Comment: Still not working - really thought it would be an easy one but this has me stumped!

Comment: I've added some more details to the answer; I think I understand better the result you're trying to achieve. It is possible the background image doesn't show up because `main` has no height; as an experiment try specifying a `height:` for that DIV.

Can you post an image sketching the effect you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

How about you just put the background image on your #main?

Answer (score 0):

Dominic is correct. Move the background properties from body to the main div and you should have what you need.

---

If I have understood your question correctly, you want to set the page background to white and have the background of your main div be whatever image you set it to - correct?

If so, setting body to:

```
body
{
  background:#fff;
}
```

should do the trick.

Now, I also noticed that the image you want to use has a smaller width than your div.
So you will want main to have the following properties:

```
#main
{
   background-image:url(myimage.jpg);
   background-position:top;
   background-repeat:repeat-x; <!-- you need this as your image is < than the div width -->
 }
```

That should do the trick. If it still doesnt work, perhaps you want to share the page link on your server. Its possible that we have misunderstood your question.